# Unable to Retrieve Data Firebase Database

Tags: java, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to retrieve data from this but I am unable to retrieve them. Someone please help me.

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrt3R.png)

[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9eI6.png)

[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9jSJ.png)

[Code 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qA48.png)

Comment: We need to see your code and any errors you might be getting.

Comment: please copy the code and put them in the question. (code that relevant to the question)

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to:

```
getUserDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getUid());
```